# How to properly define expected results in Unit Testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js, karma-jasmine

I'm learning unit testing with Jasmine but I'm confused how I should define my expected results.

```
describe("getMovieSuggestions", function() {

  it("should return movie suggestions", function() {
     parameters = parameters;

    expect(getMovieSuggestions(parameters)).toBe(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

In this case, how should I define `expectedResult`?

I see tutorials that would literally just do `expectedResult = getMovieSuggestions(parameters)`.

Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having tests?

Comment: You should either hard code the data in there, or get the data from another program that you are trying to mimic.

Comment: You'll need to know ahead of time what you expect the results to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If the `getMovieSuggestions` function returns different data for every invocation then you must `mock` the function (or its dependencies) and make sure it returns the same data every time.

Doing

```
 expectedResult = getMovieSuggestions(parameters)
 ...
 expect(getMovieSuggestions(parameters)).toBe(expectedResult);
```

does defeat the purpose and still can fail if data changes between the calls.